# How does remove function work with min priority queues that contain string values?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I understand that if I remove an element from a min priority queue, it will remove the smallest element first.  For example, if I have a min priority queue of a bunch of int values, such as `1, 2, 3`, if I call the remove function, it will remove 1.

What about if I have a min priority queue of a bunch of string values?  For example, if I have a priority queue with `"Tom", "Moe", "Brandon", "Alexander"`, would it just remove the min value according to lexicographic sorting?  If so, I imagine it would remove `"Moe"` first.  Then if I called `remove` again, it would remove `"Tom"`.

Is my understanding correct?  The below pseudo-code details the exact code I am looking at.

```
public interface Container<T>
{
 void insert(T x);  // insert x into Container
  T remove();       // remove item from Container
}

public class C<T> implements Container<T>
{
 public C() { /* constructor */ } 
 public void insert(T x) { /* insert x into C */ }
 public T remove() { /* remove item from C */ }
 //.. other methods
}

Here is a program segment that uses class C above:

Container<String> words = new C<String>();
String w1 = "Tom";
String w2 = "Dick";
String w3 = "Harry";
String w4 = "Moe";
words.insert(w1);
words.insert(w2);
words.insert(w3);
words.insert(w4);
String str = words.remove(); // remove
str = words.remove();        // remove again
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Could you please specify the concrete class which you are talking about?

Comment: @Scadge, I added the code I am looking at which should help clear it up.

Comment: Well, in this case it depends on the logic you have in the implementation of the Container interface. This is  not a standard Java class, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand.  does it help if we assume that priorities are assigned using the fact that items are Comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PriorityQueues usually accept a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in order to determine how to sort the values inside. If you don't provide one, then Java uses the [default comparison method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29): like 1 is less than 2 and "A" is less than "B".

So in your example, the default lexicographic order will be: Alexander, Brandon, Moe, Tom (like in alphabet). Also note than "a" is less than "A", so the case also matters.

Comment: This answers it perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: Check the documentation to know a bit more of how Strings are compared in Java (there may be some not totally obvious issues): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29